# How to show a digital clock in Pharo? and Cuis?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

As a very beginner in Pharo 5, I can't find how to show a Digital clock as "12:25:05" in world or/and a window. There is no ClockMorph in Pharo ?

I get what I want ! It's great :

- for a clock in World :

  ```
  |morph|     
  morph := StringMorph new.    
  morph font: (LogicalFont familyName: 'Source Sans Pro' pointSize: 20).
  morph color: Color gray.
  morph openInWorld; bounds: ((World bounds corner x)-100@0 extent: 100@20).
  [ [ true ] whileTrue: [
      morph contents: Time now print24.
      1 second wait
  ] ] fork.
  ```
- for a clock in a window with Morphic :

  ```
  |morph myWindow|
  myWindow := StandardWindow labelled: 'CLOCK'.
  myWindow addMorph:(morph := StringMorph new) frame: (0.1@(-0.2) corner: 0.9@0.9).
  myWindow beUnresizeable ; removeCloseBox ; removeCollapseBox ;
  removeExpandBox ; removeMenuBox.
  "meta-click to activate the ""morphic halo"" and close window"
  morph font: (LogicalFont familyName: 'Source Sans Pro' pointSize: 20).
  morph color: Color white.
  myWindow openInWorld; bounds: ((World bounds corner x)-140@10 extent: 130@75.0).
  [ [ true ] whileTrue: [
          morph contents: Time now print24.
          1 second wait
  ] ] fork.
  ```
- for a clock in a window with Spec :

  ```
  | view labelClock layout |
  " Configure the Spec models "    
  view := DynamicComposableModel new    
      instantiateModels: #(labelClock ButtonModel);
      extent: 128@18;
      title: 'CLOCK'
      yourself.
  " Configure the Spec layout "
  layout := SpecLayout composed
      newColumn: [ : r | r add: #labelClock];
      yourself.
  " Set up the widgets "
  view labelClock font: (LogicalFont familyName: 'Source Sans Pro' pointSize: 20).
     [ [ true ] whileTrue: [
          view labelClock label: Time now print24.
          1 second wait
  ] ] fork.
  " Open the Window "
  (view openWithSpecLayout: layout)
      centered;
      modalRelativeTo: World.
  ```

  Thank's to every body @Peter, @Bert, @aka.
- for a clock in a Morph in Cuis:

  ```
  |morph string|     
  morph := LayoutMorph newRow.  
  morph morphPosition:(Display width -160)@10 extent:150@33; color:Color skyBlue; padding:#center.  
  string := StringMorph new.
  string font: (AbstractFont familyName: 'DejaVu' pointSize: 22).
  [ [ true ] whileTrue: [
      string contents: Time now print24.
      (Delay forSeconds:1) wait
  ] ] fork.
  morph addMorph: string.
  morph openInWorld.
  ```

  But there is a Morph called "UpdatingStringMorph" in item "New morph..." in World menu that shows the time in Cuis!

Answer (score 2):

You can find out by loading the Pomodoro project from the catalog.
That contains a clock that counts back from 25 minutes, and you should be able to replace that. Or import a ClockMorph from Squeak, assuming there is one in the image.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stephan. Pomodoro looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily build your own clock, e.g.

```
morph := StringMorph new.
morph openInWorld.
[ [ true ] whileTrue: [
        morph contents: Time now print24.
        1 second wait
] ] fork.
```

`openInWorld` will add the morph to top left corner (you can drag it around with halo click), alternatively you can use `openInWindow`.

Customization can be dona via standard Morphic API (e.g. changing `color:` etc).

Comment: Morphic is not threadsafe, you shouldn't execute Morphic code from a different process. Stepping is safe. Try UpdatingStringMorph.

Comment: (UpdatingStringMorph on: [Time now print24] selector: #value) stepTime: 1000; openInWorld

Comment: @BertFreudenberg UpdatingStringMorph is squeak only. But my question is: what is the danger of thread unsafety here? Looking at the morphic code I don't see anything that could break.

Comment: Maybe not in this specific example, but in general. E.g. setting the contents could trigger a relayout when one is already in progress. The stepping mechanism is triggered from the Morphic main loop so it is guaranteed that no other event processing or layouting or drawing is going on at the same time.